# Few Solr stopwords showing up in facet search results

Tags: solr, lucene

**Problem** : Few Solr stopwords showing up in facet search results.

**Current implementation** : 
I have at least 30 to 40 stopwords in a `stopwords.txt` file. 
Solr facet search works perfectly with  stopwords like:

> for the, is, and, as

But few stopwords like

> call, state,ask

are showing up in facet search result. I tried to use solr analysis. Word show up in ST.

I am using following configuration

```xml
<field name="message" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" 
multiValued="true"/>

<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" 
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" 
            protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt"       
            ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true"   
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" 
            protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: Did you change the list of stopwords after indexing? You need to re-index after making any change to the stopwords file.

Comment: Yes I did re-index after making changes. I did it couple of times but having same issue.

Comment: Here what I found is if I removed PorterStemFilterFactory from index analyzer. Stopword stop showing in facet search results. is anyone knows reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the order of your filters. Put `StopFilterFactory` last in the chain. This should prevent stopwords from getting indexed.

```
<field name="message" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" 
multiValued="true"/>

<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" 
            protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" 
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt"       
            ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" 
            protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true"   
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

**Explanation**

The output from a previous tokenizer/filter is fed as input to the next tokenizer/filter.

From [Solr Reference Guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Understanding+Analyzers,+Tokenizers,+and+Filters)

> Filters examine a stream of tokens and keep them, transform or discard
>   them, or create new ones. **Tokenizers and filters may be combined to
>   form pipelines, or chains, where the output of one is input to the
>   next.** Such a sequence of tokenizers and filters is called an
>   analyzer and the resulting output of an analyzer is used to match
>   query results or build indices.

So if you have a word like "calling" it will first reach `StopFilterFactory` in your fieldType chain.

Since "calling" is in not a word in your stopwords.txt file, it will then go to `PorterStemFilterFactory` where "calling" is changed to "call".

Check this [website](http://9ol.es/porter_js_demo.html) to see root words using PorterStemFilterFactory) and index that word.

This is why you are still seeing stopwords in your index.

Depending on which version of Solr you are using, you might be able to see how a word like "calling" gets indexed.

```
http://YourSolrIPAddress:8983/solr/#/YourCoreORCollection/schema-browser?field=message
```

Comment: Thanks it is working. I have put stopword at the end and everything is working as expected. Thanks for the explanation.